# Drop down (select) form elements not working in Safari 4.0.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, magento, safari

I have a commerce website that I have been involved with that has been created using Magento.

http://www.littletakas.com/shop/

Some users have been complaining about the select form elements not working. If you try clicking on them they do not expand. I have been able to replicate it and it appears that these tags are not working correctly in Safari 4.0.5.

The funny thing is if I copy the HTML source code for the offending page and past it into an HTML file that resided on my machine locally, the select tags work correctly.

I suspect that it could be a JavaScript issue but I wouldn't even know where to start looking for a solution.

If anybody with the ability to test under Safari 4.0.5 is able to test the link above and give me some feedback it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just managed to narrow it down to typekit.

Comment: Found the answer http://getsatisfaction.com/typekit/topics/typekit_prevents_form_select_controls_from_working